# how to increase the queue capacity when doing a lot of queries in parallel?

Tags: multithreading, crate

I'm doing a benchmark with crate and insert a lot of records at the same time. It seems like I hit some limit (queue capacity 50) and I didn't find how to change the configuration.

> Exception in thread Thread-1:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
>       self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
>     File "createdata.py", line 60, in worker
>       cursor.execute(ins, params)
>     File "/Users/jodok/sandbox/crate-demo/amsterdam/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/crate/client/cursor.py", line 48, in execute
>       self._result = self.connection.client.sql(sql, parameters)
>     File "/Users/jodok/sandbox/crate-demo/amsterdam/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/crate/client/http.py", line 190, in sql
>       content = self._json_request('POST', self.sql_path, data=data)
>     File "/Users/jodok/sandbox/crate-demo/amsterdam/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/crate/client/http.py", line 345, in _json_request
>       self._raise_for_status(response)
>     File "/Users/jodok/sandbox/crate-demo/amsterdam/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/crate/client/http.py", line 331, in _raise_for_status
>       raise ProgrammingError(error.get('message', ''))
>   ProgrammingError: SQLActionException[RemoteTransportException[[nuc2][inet[/192.168.42.72:4300]][bulk/shard]]; nested: EsRejectedExecutionException[rejected execution (queue capacity 50) on org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction$1@23c7247f]; ]

Answer (score 0):

bulk inserts are using the *bulk* threadpool, so add this to your crate.yml configuration file to change its size:

`threadpool.bulk.queue_size: 100`

but with the current master this shouldn't be needed anymore, because crate is retrying the current bulk request on such queue size rejecting issues now.